# Prevent rsyslog from logging remote hosts messages to local /var/log/syslog

Tags: rsyslog

I use rsyslog to save logs from remote hosts to a server this way:

**Server:**

```
# Logfile for each host
$template DynaFile,"/var/log/rsyslog/%HOSTNAME%.log"
*.* -?DynaFile
```

**Clients:**

```
*.* @servername
```

This creates log files for every client host in servers `/var/log/rsyslog/` but it logs every message also to the servers `/var/log/syslog`. So it gets really bloated. How can I prevent it so that `/var/log/syslog` only contains messages from the server itself?

Comment: You'll want to look into [property based filters](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/rsyslog_conf_filter.html) since HOSTNAME is one of the syslog fields. You'll basically want to change it so that it only selects its own logs for `/var/log/syslog`

Answer (score 5):

You have to make sure that your new rules are evaluated **before** the one that logs to /var/log/syslog.
For example on Ubuntu Trusty (rsyslog 7.4.4) /etc/rsyslog.conf contains
`$IncludeConfig /etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf`
so the default rules are loaded from `/etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf`, the one for /var/log/syslog included.

In this case you can add a new file to be loaded before that one, such as `00-remote.conf`. For completeness, here's its content for a system I'm managing:

```
$template RemoteStore, "/var/log/remote/%HOSTNAME%/%timegenerated:1:10:date-rfc3339%"
:source,isequal,"NAS",-?RemoteStore
& ~
```

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me. I had to rename my configurations so that they are processed before `50-default.conf`. For example, to ensure rules in `/etc/rsyslog.d/53-firewall.conf` don't end up in syslog, I simply renamed it to `/etc/rsyslog.d/49-firewall.conf` and restarted rsyslog.

Comment: This answer is the best of all of them, because of its focus on rsyslog's **file order**, which is really important. If you're using multiple config files, ensure your specific file (by using, e.g. `00-remote.conf`) is loaded first and that your rules precede any other rules writing to `/var/log/syslog`. This way, your rules will take precedence, and the remote logs will be correctly discarded.

Answer (score 4):

Here is what works for me:

```
## For accepting syslog info from remote hosts
$template TempAuth, "/var/log/infosys/%HOSTNAME%/%PROGRAMNAME%.log"
$template TempMsg,  "/var/log/infosys/%HOSTNAME%/%PROGRAMNAME%.log"

if ($fromhost-ip != "127.0.0.1" ) then ?TempAuth
& ~
if ($fromhost-ip != "127.0.0.1" ) then  ?TempMsg
& ~
```

Comment: Why is there a duplication between `TempAuth`  and `TempMsg`?

Comment: Not working for me

Answer (score 2):

I've been working on this a lot and i think i've found a solution. I encourage others to try this and look for potentially adverse consequences. I suggest that this be implemented on lab/testing and non critical machines first.

```
$template PerHostLog,"/var/log/net-hosts/%fromhost-ip%/%fromhost-ip%.log"
$template RemoteHostFileFormat,"%TIMESTAMP% %fromhost-ip% %syslogfacility-text% %syslogtag%%msg:::sp-if-no-1st-sp%%msg:::space-cc,drop-last-lf%\n”
:inputname, isequal, "imudp" ?PerHostLog;RemoteHostFileFormat
:fromhost-ip , !isequal , "127.0.0.1" stop
```

The above 4 lines are in the top most section of my /etc/rsyslog.conf file

I'm currently watching 2 log files:

/var/log/net-hosts/10.1.1.1

and
/var/log/syslog

as I watch both, I'm seeing logs populate into the remote host file, yet not in the syslog. I restarted apache and saw log entries in syslog for this task.

Comment: Thanks for testing. But it doesn't work for me. It still logs everything to servers /var/log/syslog

Comment: The `:fromhost-ip , !isequal , "127.0.0.1" stop` line, in combination with making sure our remote logging rules in `/etc/rsyslog.d/` are executed first (see other answers here), fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

For the newer version, The below code fixed the issue.

```
input(type="imudp" port="514" ruleset="remote")
ruleset(name="remote"){
    $template DynaFile,"/var/log/rsyslog/%HOSTNAME%.log"
    if ($fromhost-ip != "127.0.0.1") then -?DynaFile
}
```